# Терминал в табах или сплитах vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim

Если ли какой либо способ, плагин чтобы запустить терминал внутри таба или сплита внутри vim?

[image: терминал внутри таба или сплина внутри vim]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26411645/4827341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я попробовал использовать tmux, и в его многочисленных терминалах действительно можно развернуть нужное рабочее окружение. Но как мне показалось он больше подходит для полноценных рабочих пространств - в одном редактор, в другом, к примеру, запущен тестовый север и выводятся логи и т. д.

Но иногда хочется иметь на расстоянии одной кнопки терминал, чтобы быстро что-то проверить или запустить. Для себя решение я нашел в [Spacevim](https://spacevim.org/), это расширение над vim и nvim, которое, помимо кучи возможностей открывает полноценный терминал в одном из буферов vim (**space** + **'**)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]